# Is it possible to get more information about where a syntax error occured from something like luaL_loadstring?

Tags: syntax, lua

`luaL_loadstring` according to the documentation returns if there was a syntax error (in the case there is one).

Is there a way to determine where Lua first determined there was a syntax error or any further information besides the return value stating there is a syntax error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an illustration for Yu Hao's answer.
Please don't be scared, this is simply excerpt from some Pascal program :-)

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
   const
      Script = 'a = 56+';  // luaL_loadstring() would fail to load this code
   var
      L: Plua_State;
begin
   // Start Lua;
   L := luaL_newstate;
   if L <> nil then
      try
         // Load Lua libraries
         luaL_openlibs(L);
         // Load the string containing the script we are going to run
         if luaL_loadstring(L, PChar(Script)) <> 0 then
            // If something went wrong, error message is at the top of the stack
            ShowMessage('Failed to load() script'#10+String(lua_tostring(L, -1)))
         else begin
            // Ask Lua to run script
            if lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0) <> 0 then
               ShowMessage('Failed to run script'#10+String(lua_tostring(L, -1)))
            else begin
               lua_getglobal(L, 'a');
               ShowMessage('OK'#10'a = ' + IntToStr(lua_tointeger(L, -1)));
            end;
         end;
      finally
         // Close Lua;
         lua_close(L);
      end;
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

[`luaL_loadstring`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_loadstring) calls [`lua_load`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_load) to do the actual work, from the manual:

> Loads a Lua chunk (without running it). If there are no errors, lua_load pushes the compiled chunk as a Lua function on top of the stack. Otherwise, **it pushes an error message.**

So you can check the return value of `luaL_loadstring`, if it returns error, check the stack for error message.

Comment: @meds I didn't really check it, but I think it's the same as checking other strings from the C API stack.